# Existing software for a gist-like intranet?

Tags: git, intranet, markdown

Recently I been thinking about how a intranet could use markdown for their documents.

Which these documents can be modified and use git for version control so they are like a gist on github (each document is a separate git repo).

Of course the document might not be markdown, could be a snippet etc. Which could be handy on a intranet (library of snippets etc).

Not sure if this is already done, but any thoughts on this?

Comment: [Gitit](https://github.com/jgm/gitit) and [Viki](http://www.owengriffin.com/?p=72) are related, although they use a single repository per site. Also [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DownmarkerWPF](http://code52.org/DownmarkerWPF/) ([github](https://github.com/Code52/DownmarkerWPF)) in combination with Git.

> MarkPad (formerly known as DownmarkerWPF) is an editor for Markdown - a widely used syntax for formatting plain text to convert to blogs, comments, and in other places like on Stack Overflow.
>
> Our aim is to create a useably, stylish new version of the project utilising Microsoft's WPF technology to provide a fresh UI for creating files that we can use to create blog posts for this, and other blogs using Markdown.
>
> [image]

<sub>**Affiliation:** Contributed ability to change font size as well as proper scrolling. Might not be in latest binary, but is in source...</sub>